# How to get max time from list of times?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to **find max time** from a list of time formats in **Java**

For example it looks like that:

```
String times = "11:20, 12:20, 13:20, 14:20, 15:20"
```

How can I get max time (for this example 15:20) from my times?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Post the code that's not working.

Comment: You can split this string by ", " and sort the result

Comment: Will the list always be sorted? So it’s a matter of taking the last time from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below code ;

```
String times = "11:20, 12:20, 13:20, 14:20, 15:20";
String[] allTimes = times.replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
String maxTime = Stream.of(allTimes).max(String::compareTo).get();
```

Now you can convert `maxTime` to `LocalTime` or whatever you want.

Comment: Converting to `LocalTime` will be a good idea in many situations, but then I’s prefer to do it before finding the max. You get input validation from parsing each time, and comparing times is more natural, better conveys the intention than comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1) Operates with these times as strings:

```
String timesString = "11:20, 12:20, 13:20, 14:20, 15:20";
//split to array of ["11:20", "12:20", ..., "15:20"]
String[] timesStringArray = timesString.split(", ");
//find lexicographic maximum (in this case it will be equals to max time)
String maxDateString = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(timesStringArray));
```

2) Operates with these times as Dates:

```
String timesString = "11:20, 12:20, 13:20, 14:20, 15:20";
//split to array of ["11:20", "12:20", ..., "15:20"]
String[] timesStringArray = timesString.split(", ");
//create formatting string for our case to convert string to Date
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
//create list of dates
List<Date> times = new ArrayList<>();
for (String time : timesStringArray) {
    try {
        times.add(dateFormat.parse(time));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//find max time as Date
Date maxDate = Collections.max(times);
// convert back to String if needed
String maxDateString = dateFormat.format(maxDate);
```

Comment: Using a library class for the times is a good idea. Not `Date`. It’s long outdated, poorly designed and not suitable for a time of day without date and without time zone or offset. And `SimpleDateFormat` is renowned for trouble. Avoid those two. `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java data and time API, is right for a time of day and will parse strings like `11:28` without any explicit formatter. Much recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String times = "11:20, 12:20, 13:20, 14:20, 15:20";
    String[] timeArray = times.split(", ");
    Optional<LocalTime> maxTime = Arrays.stream(timeArray)
            .map(LocalTime::parse)
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    maxTime.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

This prints:

> 15:20

I prefer to use proper types for my values rather than having everyting in strings. `LocalTime` is the right class for a time of day (without date and without time zone or offset).